# How do I measure the characteristics of a voltage divider in a QUCS simulation?

Tags: simulation, voltage-divider, qucs

How do I measure the characteristics of a voltage divider in QUCS?

Below is what I have tried thus far, using Qucs 0.0.15 on Ubuntu 10.04

I want to measure how the voltage at the center of a voltage divider changes based on R2 in the schematic below.  I am attempting to simulate this in QUCS using a DC simulation and a parameter sweep.

This is how I have it set up below, but the output is constant from what I can tell, which does not make sense.

[image: schematic]

[image: graph setup]
[image: tabular output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like SPICE simulators there's a difference between simulation parameters and reference designators.

Here, the reference designator for the lower resistor is R2. The R value of R2 is always 50 ohms. To use a parameter, you must assign it to the parameter name surrounded by curly braces. So the R value of resistor R2 should be `{R2}` to have resistor R2's R value set to the parameter R2.

To make things a bit more clear, change the parameter sweep param to RLOW and the value of R2 to `{RLOW}`. The simulation should work as expected and you'll get the correct results (yeah, I realize that my voltage source isn't at the same level as the OP so the actual values will be different).

[image: schematic]

[image: results]

Comment: Bless you! That worked wonderfully.

Comment: Stack exchange is the coolest system out there!

Comment: I don't think you need the curly brackets in QUCS